# Can I use Django admin panel as the only view for the admin of the site not for developer?

Tags: python, django

I am creating an E-Learning system (similar to Udemy) where I have instructors, students and admins. I was thinking to create a panel for each one of these stakeholders.

My question is, can I use Django's admin panel, where I need this panel to block users and block a course and so on?

Thank you.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Not 100% Sure but as much as i know django admin panel can be access by superuser only. Student Account and Developer Account cant access admin panel unless you provide them staff and Superuser access. And giving them access means they are same as admins!maybe not sure!

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).